# altering css / asset weight after it's been added?

Tags: 7

I'm using [context add assets](http://drupal.org/project/context_addassets) to add a stylesheet.

[image]

It's currently being loaded correctly based on a context; but now it's loading before my global.css stylesheet. I would like blog to load after global.css.

[image]

Is it possible to alter the weight of the blog.css stylesheet via preprocessing? If so could you provide an example?

Comment: You could try adding more exact selectors that will not be overridden by the ones in `global.css` or you can use the `!important` property where the styles get overridden.

Comment: That's what i'm trying to avoid. Using !important is not the best practice IMHO.

Comment: Yeah but the whole point of a theme is to override the output/style of what modules define. That's why it is included at the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`hook_css_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_css_alter/7):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_css_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_css_alter(&$css) { 
  $css['sites/all/themes/FUZZYGREYEDOUT/css/blog.css']['weight'] = 10;
}
```